# Minor alignment issue in the pagination div

Tags: bug, design, pagination

There is a minor alignment issue in the pagination div. There is no space in between the `prev` and `1` div.

The same can be reproduced in the following page's pagination div (which is in the bottom of the page):

- [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular)
- [Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=quarter)
- [Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2)

Sample screenshot from Tags page:

> [image: pagination]